# Changelog? Changes specific to stackoverflow? sliding voting thing & clicking reveals votes?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a changelog and was only able to find one on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange?answertab=active#tab-top) which I think is for all sites?

I noticed stackoverflow has made some changes. The widget that allows you to vote on questions or answers slide with the scroll bar. And a slightly older feature now - if you click on the vote number it reveals the upvotes/downvotes separately.

I can't find these mentioned on the meta.SE changelog. Is there a separate changelog for different sites?

The above mentioned changed only appear on stackoverflow.com. Are they going to be only on stackoverflow or can I expect them to be on other sites as well in the future?

Comment: The view vote splits is a "privilege" you get at 1000 rep

Comment: The sliding vote buttons are only as an A/B test. The feature may end up being completely removed at the end of testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The widget that allows you to vote on questions or answers slide with
>   the scroll bar.

So this is A/B test that is currently running in StackOverflow, and which is showing up in your right side bar (if not, you can see more info about it here [A/B testing the sticky vote controls - give your feedback, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please)), and it even can't be not implemented.

> And a slightly older feature now - if you click on the vote number it
>   reveals the upvotes/downvotes separately.

As you said this old in SO, which is only for users with rep+1000 (1k), you can find the privileges under the tab privileges in your profile page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

So as far as the A/B test it is only for SO, but for the privileges I'm sure each site has its owns privileges like [Super User site](https://superuser.com/help/privileges) has.